# Resolve a partial/incomplete Route in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

I have an API controller that lives at `/api/Test/Foo/1234`

```
[Area("Api")]
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name= "TestRouteName")]
    public IActionResult Foo(int id)
    {   
        ....
    }
}
```

Within a view I can correctly resolve this URL with `@Url.RouteUrl("TestRouteName", new { id = 1234 })` to `/api/Test/Foo/1234`

Is there a way for me to just return `/api/Test/Foo/` (to be later consumed by JavaScript) ?

I've tried `@Url.RouteUrl("UserProfile")` but this returns an empty string, `@Url.Action("Foo", "Test", new { area = "api" }` returns `/Test/Foo?area=api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your default routing of "id" is actually adding it into the url, instead of using it as a query parameter. Try something like below.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "TestRouteName")]
    public IActionResult Foo(int id)
    {
        .........
    }
```

**View**

```
    @(Url.RouteUrl("TestRouteName"))
```

**Url to access View**

```
    api/Test/Foo?id=1234
```

Or you could just use the following to get what you want.

```
    @(Url.Action("Foo", "Test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow nothing (null) to be given for your route parameter `id` you should put a questionmark `?` after the name ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference)):

```
[HttpGet("{id?}", Name= "TestRouteName")]
public IActionResult Foo(int id)
{   
    ....
}
```

Note, however, that if you don't make your `int id` parameter nullable the default value for `id` will be `0` when the route is accessed.